# How to make the background color of the selected area using image maps

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<map name="instalacja">
<area shape="poly" coords="122,36,281" href="#ppg" title="The Powerpuff Girls" alt="The Powerpuff Girls">
<area shape="poly" coords="864,667," href="#cn" title="Cartoon Network" alt="Cartoon Network" >            
<area  class ="p" shape="poly" coords="1010,297,995," data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" title="Buttercup" alt="Tył" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#00FF00';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='transparent';">
</map>
```

How do I assign a color or border area? I've tried different ways but none of them work?
Thanks

Comment: What ways have you tried?

Comment: I tried by adding a diva and giving the parameters, the css, by giving the parameters of the same area

Comment: Check this out : http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/

Comment: I do not know why it does not. You do not know what to change to perhaps drawn lines of the following points are shown. Do you have to do it in jquery?
Thanks